# Problems with Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, conways-game-of-life

I am stuck with a problem that I haven't been successful in finding the solution through other people's post. We are following standard rules for Conway's Game of Life.

So far I have been able to create the 2d array as well as populate the array with a random character of '-' for dead and 'O' for alive (The letter O not the number zero). I believe that I am going through and checking all of the neighbors correctly. * The reason I used try/catch is because it was the only way I could figure out how to avoid getting an out of bounds error message.

My main issue is that I'm not sure if I am going through the array correctly when checking/changing values. Also I am not sure how to go about printing the "updated" 2d array after applying the live/die rules to the entire array.

As of right now, the output prints the randomized array once, then prints the exact same array again, then asks if i want to continue ( Go through the while loop again). If I choose 'y', I get the error message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

I'm beyond lost, any ideas will help as I am about 3 weeks into python.

Here is my code:

```
import random

numrows = 25
numcols = 25


def rnd():
    rn = random.randint(0,1)
    return rn


def initial():

    grid = []
    count = 0

    for x in range(numrows):
        grid.append([])
        for y in range(numcols):
            rand=random.randrange(1,3)
            if(rand == 1):
                grid[x].append('O')
            else:
                grid[x].append('-')

    for x in grid:    
        print(*x, sep=' ',end="\n") #prints initial grid with random values

    print("")# space for clarity sake
    print("")#      "       "

    answer = 'y'
    count = 0

    while(answer == 'y'):

        #This is where I am checking each neighbor. Adding 1 to count for each
        #live neighbor.

        for r in range(0,numrows):
            for c in range(0,numcols):


                try:
                    if(grid[r-1][c-1] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    if(grid[r-1][c] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    if(grid[r-1][c+1] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    if(grid[r][c-1] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:

                    if(grid[r][c+1] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    if(grid[r+1][c-1] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    if(grid[r+1][c] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass

                try:
                    if(grid[r+1][c+1] == 'O'):
                        count += 1

                except:
                    pass


                #this is where I am applying the rules of living or dying
                #based on how many neighbors there are.

                if(grid[r][c] == '-'):
                        if(count == 3):
                            grid[r][c].append('O')

                if(grid[r][c] == 'O'):
                    if(count < 2):
                        grid[r][c].append('-')

                if(grid[r][c] == 'O'):
                    if(count == 2 or count == 3):
                        grid[r][c].append('O')

                if(grid[r][c] == 'O'):
                    if(count > 3):
                        grid[r][c].append('-')

                for r in grid:                 #This is a problem area as i dont
                    print(*r, sep=' ',end="\n")#know how to print the grid 

                answer = input("Continue? y or n( lower case only): ")

                if(answer != 'y'):
                    print(" Hope you had a great life! Goodbye!")
```

Comment: show full error message (Traceback). There are other usefull information - like line of code which makes problem.

Comment: yoiu have to check `r-1 > -1` before you use `r-1` so you will no need some `try/except`. The same with `c-1 > -1` and `r+1 < numrows` and `c+1 < numcols`

Comment: `grid[r][c]` is char, not list so you can't use `grid[r][c].append('O')` - you need `grid[r][c] = 'O'`

Comment: you use `r` in `for r in grid:` but `r` is used in `for r in range(0,numrows):` and `grid[r][c]` too - it gives you `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

Comment: you have to use `elif` in `if(grid[r][c] == 'O'):` (and others) because you first change `-` into `O` and next you check `O` in the same place. You could print grid and ask `continue` outside of both `for` loop. Now you draw after every changed cell.

Comment: main problem - you count for one cell then you change value in this cell so for next cell you use different grid but you have to use original. You need second grid to put modification. After all modification you replace previous grid with new grid

Comment: or first make calculation for all cells and later change values in original grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I was able to follow everything you were saying as it pertained to my code. I have revised the code based on the information that you have given me. I am receiving an error with the if statement when I check to see if(r-1 > -1). I keep getting this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    initial()
 line 32, in initial
    if((r-1) > -1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

What is the proper format for this operation inside the if statement?

Comment: do other things and later return to `if r-1 > -1:`. And use `print()` to check values and conditions - it simple method to debug code (if you don't know how to use debuger)

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int' ` it is problem with `for r in grid:` - you use the same variable as row index and as row-list. You have to use different name in this `for` loop ie. `for row in grid:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem: the crash occurs at the if line:

```
                if(grid[r][c] == '-'):  # <=== here on this line
                        if(count == 3):
                            grid[r][c].append('O')
```

On that line, `r` is no longer an integer, but it is a list. But, why? The answer occurs a few lines later:

```
            for r in grid:                 #This is a problem area as i dont
                print(*r, sep=' ',end="\n")#know how to print the grid
```

In this block, r was an int, but now you turned it into a list. I acknowledge your comment there, on not knowing how to print the grid, so may I suggest a quickie:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(cell) for cell in row) for row in grid))
```

This way, you are not overwriting the variable `r`.